# Logstash+Kibana: как убрать из списка поля, отправляемые filebeat

Tags: логирование, elasticsearch

ELK stack:
сервер - elasticsearch + logstash + kibana 
клиент - filebeat

Создаю систему централизованного логирования. Logstash отдает в Kibana несколько полей, которые дублируются и которые не получается убрать: beat.hostname, beat.name, host. Везде в качестве значения отдается имя компютера на клиента (которое по умолчанию отправляет filebeat).

поле host я убрал с помощью:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "java" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}   %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:thread} %{JAVACLASS:class} %{GREEDYDATA:log}" }
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "beat.hostname", "beat.name", "host" ]
  }
 }
}
```

А `beat.hostname` и `beat.name` убрать не получается.
Как можно убрать эти три значение, чтобы име хоста выводилось один раз???

Comment: Я не гуру ELK, но тут имхо плохо все. Логстэш не отдает в кибану, он отдает в эластиксёрч. Фильтр grok сам умеет remove_field, mutate тут не в тему. Условие вашего фильтра по типу java выполняет только grok, а удаление полей вы вынесли за это условие, что логически не принадлежит этому условию, а значит и обработке логов типа “java”. Но это не точно (с)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references) говорит что имена полей нужно писать в квадратных скобках, исключая поля верхнего уровня:

> The syntax to access a field is [fieldname]. If you are referring to a
>   top-level field, you can omit the [] and simply use fieldname. To
>   refer to a nested field, you specify the full path to that field:
>   [top-level field][nested field].

То есть нужно записать ваши поля как [beat][hostname], [beat][name].